# Изменить styleSheet для QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Что нужно прописать в styleSheet, что бы изменить цвет этого элемента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для изменения стиля углового элемента можно использовать следующий styleSheet:

```css
QTableCornerButton::section {
    background: red;
}
```